# Dart remote isolates like remote akka actors

Tags: dart, akka, actor, dart-isolates, remote-actors

Is there something in dart like remote isolates similar to [akka remote actors](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/remoting.html)?

I am not talking about spawning isolate from *.dart file from remote location as [spawnUri](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-isolate.Isolate#id%5fspawnUri) does. I am trying to find out if there can be a running isolate in remote machine that you can pass message to and get response from it over a network.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not supported out of the box. You can, however, write a web server with [dart:io.HttpServer](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart%3aio.HttpServer) and start isolates following user's requests.